# Python: URL images download. The URL contains an accented letter. I'm getting an error

Tags: python

There is a problem that the URLs in the .csv file contain accented letters (á, é, í, etc.). If it has an accented character in it, I get an error.

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request


def url_to_jpg(i, url, file_path):

    filename = 'image-{}.jpg'.format(i)
    full_path = '{}{}'.format(file_path, filename)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)

    print('{} saved.'.format(filename))

    return None

FILENAME = 'imgs_urls.csv'
FILE_PATH = 'images/'

urls = pd.read_csv(FILENAME, encoding ='latin1')


for i, url in enumerate(urls.values):
    url_to_jpg(i, url[0], FILE_PATH)
```

Picture of the error:

[image: Picture of the error]

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Try `urls = pd.read_csv(FILENAME, encoding ='utf-8')`?

Comment: I tried, not good!

Comment: Is it possible to post that one line of url which causes the trouble?

Comment: You might want to add `url = urllib.parse.quote(url, encoding='utf8', safe = '://')` before `urllib.request.urlretrieve`

Comment: It works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use URLs with non-ASCII characters, you need to clean/convert them before.

In your case, you would add the `clean_url` function below into your loop. This worked with your link in `python 3:`

1. `urllib.parse.urlsplit` splits the URL into the components
2. `urllib.parse.quote` will properly escape the Unicode
   characters
3. `urllib.parse.urlunsplit` will join it back together

.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

def url_to_jpg(url, file_path):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_path)
    print('{} saved.'.format(file_path))

def clean_url(url): 
    url = urllib.parse.urlsplit(url)
    url = list(url)
    url[2] = urllib.parse.quote(url[2])
    url = urllib.parse.urlunsplit(url)
    return url

url = u'<url_with_non_ascii_char>'

url = clean_url(url)
url_to_jpg(url, "test.jpg")
```